# Are two definitions of "smooth planar domain" related?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables

Let's consider non-empty open subsets of the real plane.

Definition 1. Suppose  $\gamma: S^1 \to  \mathbb R ^2$ is a $C^{k,\alpha}$ Jordan curve ($0 \leq \alpha<1$) with $\gamma ' $ non-vanishing. The bounded component of $\mathbb R ^2 - \gamma(S^1 )$ may be called a  $C^{k,\alpha}$ planar domain.

Definition 2.
However, there is a "standard" definition of "smoooth domains", namely, a non-empty open set $U \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is called $C^{k,a}$ if for each $z \in \partial U$ there exists an $r>0$ and a $C^{k,\alpha}$ function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $B(z,r) \cap U = B(z,r) \cap \{(x,y):y>f(x)\} $(upto rotations and reflections of the coordinate axes).

It is clear that the latter may not imply the former, since the former will require the domain to be simply connected. I am interested in the following questions.

1. Does the former implies the latter? (I am particularly interested in this direction.)
2. Does the latter implies the former, provided that $U$ is simply connected?

I tried googling with keywords something like "planar domain smoothness" "smooth Jordan domains" etc. but I could not find definitive answers to this question, although this question seems to be very natural.
(I suspect that some form of Caratheodory's extension theorm for conformal mappings may be useful... )

Thanks to everyone in the community.

Comment: 1 is always true due to the implicit function theorem. 2 is true is you add the assumption that $U$ is bounded (and simply connected), otherwise a half-plane is a counter-example.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for your comment. Maybe I am being stupid, but how do I use the implicit function theorem? Could you please elaborate your comment as an answer?